# Modulate Bipolar(?) signal

Tags: filters, phase, modulation, analog, digital-to-analog

I want to modulate this signal if possible with an Arduino, but have no idea what circuit can help me here. Let's ignore the timing and the measurements from the image for a moment, my problem is more about the alternating shape of the signal.

I'm a beginner here and learning a lot at the moment. I don't wan't any complete circuits or code, but would be grateful if u could push me in the right direction. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Let's start by clarifying your question. What do you mean by "modulation"?

Comment: So a 1 is a shrug (¯\_(ツ)_/¯) and a 0 is nothing?  You want to make that specific shape with an Arduino?  Could you zoom your scope in a bit (increase the vertical gain, and maybe speed it up) so we can see that in detail?  Is it OK if your overall shape is riding on 2.5V, goes down to 0V, and up to 5V?  Does the output impedance matter?

Comment: So let's assume we have 5V DC and I want to get this shape with 4V peak, 2V low and a  center of 3V with the shape shown above (I just made the numbers up). Sorry, hard to find the correct english terms.

Comment: @TimWescott yes the numbers are fine in the end it's no about coping this signal. I want to understand how to create it. Like down from 5 to 2.5V then down to 0 and up to 5 and so on. I tried some transistor (Mosfets) / voltage divider circuits but had no luck.

Comment: @MBaz, with modulation I mean: To be able to apply this signal to an external, say 12V circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a signal that rides at VSS/2, goes down to 0V and up to VSS, just use a pair of GPIO pins, each with a $10\mathrm{k\Omega}$ resistor, with the far ends connected together.  When both pins are high you'll get VSS, when both are low you'll get 0V, when one is high and the other low you'll get VSS/2.

Then sequence the pins to get the pattern you want.  If you need something that's faster and has less jitter than you can accomplish by bit-banging the pins, use a pair of timer outputs and sequence them in hardware (which you may not be able to do with the ATMega found in most Arduinos, and which the Arduino hand-holding software may not allow you to do easily -- it's your job to figure that part out).

To get your 2V, 3V, 4V pattern, you'll need up to four resistors, connected together in the middle, and to VSS, GPIO_n, GPIO_{n+1}, and ground on the other ends.  Finding their value takes some algebra, but it's straightforward if you know basic circuits.

Comment: Thanks, will experiment with this.

Comment: Worked exactly how I wanted it, the bit-banging I haven't tried yet, but I will. The math was no problem. Thanks.